# Order by select count(*) and LIMIT is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, performance, query-optimization

I have this query in my program, when I do some sorting with select count(*) field from the query, I dont know why, it very slow when running that query.

The problem is when i do some ordering from `posts_count`, it run more slower than i do ordering with the other field.

Here's the query:
`select 'tags'.*, (select count(*) from 'posts' inner join 'post_tag' on 'posts'.'id' = 'post_tag'.'post_id' where 'tags'.'id' = 'post_tag'.'tag_id') as 'posts_count' from 'tags' order by 'posts_count' asc limit 15 offset 0;`

Here's the execution time :
[image]

Please someone help me to improve this query , Thank you.

What i expect is the query can be run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tags AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_tag AS pt ON t.id = pt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count ASC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
```

You should make sure `post_tag` has an index starting with the `tag_id` column. You didn't include your table definition in your question, so I must assume the index is there. If the primary key starts with `tag_id`, that's okay too.

You don't need to join to `posts`, if I can assume that a row exists in `post_tag` means it must reference an existing row in `posts`. You can get the information you need only by joining to `post_tag`.